# Appengine (Java) webservice needs refresh?

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-app-engine, gwt

I have created an Application using Appengine(Java) and GWT. Now I'm communicating to an android device with my Application using WebServices. But after some hours it failed to connect. Means my webservice stops working and to overcome this I had to refresh my application.

How can I handle this situation? Are there any ways my webservice stay active 24*7 in AppEngine?

My webservice body is :

```
    class webservice extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //What i want to do
       }
}
```

Comment: You need to fix the bug in your code that causes the app to stuck

Comment: There is nothing in webservice code... Webservice is just for retrieving data from appengine database.

Comment: So there's a problem with this db retrieval code. Appengine doesn't stuck by itself (and when it does because of some issue on google side, which could happen once a few months probably, it gets restarted automatically, no worries)